# A few basic Matplotlib questions regarding color palettes, graph transparency and x axis density

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Yo, first question asked on stackoverflow. Get hyped, it's a noobie one. :)

I'm using Matplotlib to plot a basic barplot graph:

```
ind = np.arange(num_of_values)  # the x locations for the groups
graph_values = dataCount.iloc[:,2]
width = 0.30       # the width of the bars

plt.style.use("ggplot")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
barplot = ax.bar(ind+0.15, graph_values, width, color='blue', edgecolor='black')

ax.set(ylim=[0,1])
ax.set_ylabel('Probability', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(('1', '2', '3'))

autolabel(barplot)

plt.show()
```

I was wondering:

1. Can I set the fill's opacity / transparency of the plotted bars?
2. Can I assign a color palette to the bars of the graph without using Seaborn?
3. How can I simply get the bars closer to each other (make the spacing between each tick smaller)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Re 1: Most matplotlib functions have an `alpha` parameter that controls opacity, which is a float beetween 0 and 1.

```
barplot = ax.bar(ind+0.15, graph_values, width, color='blue', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.7)
```

Re 2: You can specify the color of bars directly by giving it a list of named colors (`color = ['blue', 'red', 'salmon', 'crimson', 'azure', ...]`) or array of color values with the same length as your heights.

```
random_colors = np.random.rand(len(ind) , 3)
barplot = ax.bar(ind+0.15, graph_values, width, color=random_colors, edgecolor='black')
```

Re 3: Reduce the x values:

```
ind = np.arange(num_of_values/2., step=0.5)  # the x locations for the groups
```

---

Note for future questions:

1. Try not to ask more than one question in one post.
2. Try to make your code example self-contained. For example, in your snippet, we do not know the variables `dataCount` or `num_of_values` so if you have a problem, we cannot reproduce it ourselves.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for the help and the tips! Will keep them in mind. And to not repeat another arbitrary "thanks" comment: can you briefly question what you did on question 3? Do I write that same line for any number of values? (I tried playing with the division and step attribute, and sometimes I got an error, can't figure out what's the logic there..)

Comment: You need as many values in `ind` as you have in `graph_values`. `numpy.arange` will step with stepsize `step` up to the specified maximum. So if you decrease the stepsize, you will get more `ind` values back. To offset that, you need to decrease the maximum as well.